# DLL, Form and Thread (all in one) problem in delphi

Tags: multithreading, delphi, forms, dll

there is a very complex application which i try to build.

There is a DLL library which i create. I put a form in it and i put a Thread in it.

in DLL i have a function:

```
procedure ShowForm; stdcall;
var
Form1 : TFormSNVFL7;
begin
  Form1 := TFormSNVFL7.Create(nil);
  Form1.Show;
end;
```

i create a form and show it. there isn't problem in here.
I add a thread to this dll.
i put a timer on the form. after a couple of seconds i create a thread and run it. everything is going normal but when i try to change anything of the form, nothing happen.

in synchronize function i try to change a label on it but nothing happen.

Here is the files:

DLL pas:

```
library uploader;

uses
  SysUtils,
  Classes,
  Forms,
  UploaderForm in 'UploaderForm.pas' {FormUploader},
  ThreadUpload in 'ThreadUpload.pas';

{$R *.res}

procedure ShowForm; stdcall;
var
  upForm: TFormUploader;
begin
  upForm := TFormUploader.Create(nil);
  upForm.Show;
end;

exports
ShowForm;

begin
end.
```

Form pas:

```
unit UploaderForm;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, acPNG, ExtCtrls, JvExExtCtrls, JvImage, JvExControls, JvLabel,
  JvAnimatedImage, JvGIFCtrl, ComCtrls, JvExComCtrls, JvProgressBar, StdCtrls,
  FileCtrl, JvDriveCtrls;

type
  TFormUploader = class(TForm)
    imgRunning: TJvImage;
    imgReady: TJvImage;
    imgUpdate: TJvImage;
    JvLabel1: TJvLabel;
    JvLabel2: TJvLabel;
    imgConnect: TJvImage;
    imgUpload: TJvImage;
    imgCheck: TJvImage;
    JvLabel3: TJvLabel;
    JvLabel4: TJvLabel;
    JvLabel5: TJvLabel;
    JvLabel6: TJvLabel;
    imgRun: TJvImage;
    imgOK: TJvImage;
    imgDone: TJvImage;
    JvProgressBar1: TJvProgressBar;
    JvLabel7: TJvLabel;
    fileList: TJvFileListBox;
    Timer1: TTimer;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  FormUploader: TFormUploader;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

Uses ThreadUpload;

procedure TFormUploader.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
imgUpdate.Picture := imgReady.Picture;
imgConnect.Picture := imgReady.Picture;
imgUpload.Picture := imgReady.Picture;
imgCheck.Picture := imgReady.Picture;
imgRun.Picture := imgReady.Picture;
imgOK.Picture := imgReady.Picture;
fileList.Directory := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'csvexport/';
end;

procedure TFormUploader.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
UpThread: TThread;
begin
Timer1.Enabled := False;

UpThread := UploadThread.Create(true);
UpThread.Create;
UpThread.Resume;

end;

end.
```

Thread pas:

```
unit ThreadUpload;

interface

uses
  Classes, UploaderForm;

type
  UploadThread = class(TThread)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

implementation

{ UploadThread }

procedure UploadThread.Execute;
begin
  With FormUploader do
  begin
    imgUpdate.Picture := imgRunning.Picture;
  end;
end;

end.
```

i cannot solve this problem.

Comment: Why you are calling Upload.Create after you've created your thread object? I don't see imgRunning declared in your code. Why are you using thread for such a task?

Comment: imgRunning is a form object. it's creating on form create. i put a jvImage component on my form and rename it as imgRunning. it doesnt matter. when i try to do this, same problem: Label1.Caption := 'anything'; nothing has changed...

Comment: by the way, this is the begining of the task. I'll use IndyFTP to upload database files. I'll get data from an interbase server, than convert them to csv file, upload them to the server and run them on server (my server producer does not support remote connect for MySQL) etc.

Comment: I'm going to be blunt. It looks like you're trying to do something complicated just for the sake of it. That's not a very practical thing to do. We write programs to _solve problems_ - not make life difficult. Without a purpose, it's far more difficult to help you out. This is most aptly illustrated by the fact that your thread does nothing apart from an arbitrary assigment, exits and is done! Your thread doesn't have a **purpose**. Decide **what** you want to do first - not _how_ you want to do it.

Comment: When you have a specfic problem to solve, there is every possibility we can help you find a solution without a bunch of the complications you're creating for yourself.

Answer (score 8):

`TThread.Synchronize()` does not work in a DLL by default, as the sync queue that `Synchronize()` posts to is local to the executable that is calling it. In other words, when `Synchronize()` is called by the application, it posts to a queue that is local to the exe file.  When `Synchronize()` is called by a DLL, it posts to a queue that is local to the dll file.  When the application pumps its sync queue during idle times, it will not pump the DLL's queue automatically.  You have to export a function from your DLL that your application can then call when needed, such as in the `TApplication.OnIdle` event or in a timer.  That exported function can then call the RTL's `CheckSynchronize()` function to pump the DLL's sync queue.

Answer (score 0):

Simple

You are changing a property from the FormUploader var from the unit UploaderForm in the UpThread

But in the unit DLL.pas you are creating other object from TFormUploader

Try to do this in the procedure that show the form:

```
procedure ShowForm; stdcall;
begin
  FormUploader := TFormUploader.Create(nil);
  FormUploader.Show;
end;
```

Do this, and the problem are solved

Comment: This will work, but I sugest that you make a review in your dll, verifying if the timer is really necessary and the implementation need to be in other thread... but if you only doing this to study multithreading, it's no problem

Answer (score 0):

Your problem results from using VCL and threading. You should *never* call VCL related code from a thread without using synchronization mechanisms.

Normally you create a VCL application by using TApplication and TApplication.Run() to create a main loop of your program. The main loop handles windows messages and other stuff, but also calls CheckSynchronize() whereas CheckSynchronize() looks up whether there is call queued that should be synchronized (that is a call that is added to the queue by using TThread.Synchronize()). So when you create a thread i runs concurrently to the main loop and that's where your problem begins.

You should either move the picture assignment code to a separate method in TFormUploader and call that method by using TThread.Synchronize() or use other synchronization mechanisms like event objects (TEvent / CreateEvent()).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue trying to update a `TToolButton` icon in the main EXE, from a callback function invoked by the DLL. The DLL invokes the callback function in response to a broadcast to channel message sent via a [DataSnap implementation](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/41374), I think in a child thread.

Accessing the `TToolButton` directly from the EXE callback function results in flickering the `TToolBar` and disappearing the icons.

I created a `TThread` object and the interaction with the `TToolButton` is managed using the `TThread.Synchonize()` function into the main thread: this solved the problem for me.

```
interface    
type
  TCallBackThread=class(TThread)

  private
    procedure DoInSync;
  public
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;
var
  CallBackThread: TCallBackThread;

implementation

procedure TCallBackThread.DoInSync;
begin
  // Jobs to be done in main thread
end;

procedure TCallBackThread.Execute;
begin
  inherited;
  Synchronize(DoInSync);
end;
```

The callback function into the EXE is:

```
procedure ConnectWf_Callback(s: PAnsiChar); stdcall;
begin
  if not Assigned(CallBackThread) then begin
    CallBackThread := TCallBackThread.Create(true);
    CallBackThread.Resume;
  end else begin
    CallBackThread.Execute;
  end;
end;
```